# How can I use (and edit) a project in multiple unrelated solutions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

Say I have some common assembly that I use in several solutions, just a collection of useful code. How can I reference it in multiple solutions without having to copy a DLL to each of them any time I edit it? Preferably I could have it editable through multiple solutions (have it in them as a project rather than a reference), but this is not a must, and I'd settle for only editing it through it's own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the project in your solution and then reference the DLL in your project.

To add Project to solution:

1. right-click on solution
2. Add
3. Add existing project.
4. then navigate to the location of the project on your drive and select it.

To reference the DLL:

1. open project in which you want to reference the other DLL
2. right-click on reference
3. add reference.

In the reference-Windows on the right hand-side there should be a tab called solution. There you can choose references from different projects in your solution. 
Using this windows you can also reference the DLL directly. So you actually don't need to reference the entire project.

sources:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx

Comment: See, but this is the thing. If I edit the library in my common code library in one solution, the others don't seem to receive the changes.

Comment: you can reference the output-DLL directly from the other project. 
How are the others connected to your changes? Do you use TFS?

Comment: No, I don't. Will the other projects update if I rebuild the dll?

Comment: after you rebuild your project, their projects will be updated as soon as they rebuild theirs. I assume they reference your output-DLL direclty via filesystem. This is a quick&ditry-way. You should use Project-references if possible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ez524kew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Project references seem to require the projects to be in the same solution.